# should we prevent some sources?

Tags: discussion, sources

there are some sources/websites that are against Islam completely, and gives people wrong information by fraudulently translating into english .

for example : www.thereligionofpeace.com

should we prevent that ? and if we should, how to do that ?

for example, we can make the community vote for sources/websites such as questions

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be an unnecessary concern.  For the most part, any post that's relying on information from an "obviously bad" site would just not be a good post; it will get downvoted, closed and/or deleted as the situation warrants, just like any other bad post.

In the off-chance that somebody actually comes up with a good post, while relying on such a bad source, it can simply be edited to point to somewhere more reliable.

There's no need to complicate matters, when the system as-is should be able to handle the situation without trouble (God willing).

Answer (score 2):

Good question - I think there is no need for an explicit policy regarding this (plus, this will lead to discussion/argument about which sites to include in such a list, this list can never be exhaustive, etc.)

If someone links to an extremely Islamophobic and hate-filled site like the one you referred to, just point it out in the comments and ask the poster to change or remove it. Depending on the context you can also flag it.

I can also imagine a sincere question linking to some material on those websites asking what's wrong with them.